# uncountability of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following proof for the uncountability of the real numbers (not rigorous written at all by me):

Take the interval
$$
\ (a,b) \,
$$
we assume the real numbers to be countable, being (1) any sequence of real numbers
$$\ \omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, ...  (1)\,$$
Next, we want to "shrink" the interval by taking the first two numbers of the sequence (1) that are found inside this interval, denoting the smaller and the bigger by $\ a^1\,$ and $\ b^1\,$ respectively, and creating a new interval
$$\ (a^1,b^1) \,$$
Doing the same for $\ (a^1,b^1)\,$ we reach a new interval $\ (a^2,b^2) \,$ and so on, where the sequence $\ a^1,a^2, a^3, ... \,$ is increasing and $\ b^1,b^2,b^3,... \,$ is decreasing. And so we have a sequence of nested intervals.
By doing that sequence of steps we may reach a defined last interval $\ (a^N,b^N), \,$ meaning we have a finite number of intervals. Or we might "reach" an interval $\ (a^\infty ,b^\infty) \,$, where $\lim_{ n\to \infty} a^n =a^\infty$ and $\lim_{ n\to \infty} b^n =b^\infty$. Listing the possibilities we have:

1. For the finite steps we can have any number Y inside this interval prove the contradiction.
2. For the infinite steps, where we reach $\ a^\infty>b^\infty\,$,any number Y inside the interval $\ (a^\infty,b^\infty)\,$ can be used to show the contradiction.
3. For the infinite steps, where we get $\ a^\infty=b^\infty\,$, Cantor stated that this number could not be included in the sequence (1) shown above.

I would like to understand how to justify that a number Y actually exists in those intervals of cases 1 and 2. As well as why Cantor stated that the number $\ a^\infty=b^\infty\,$ would not be part of the sequence (1).

Comment: Not clear to me what $a^1$ and $b^1$ are supposed to be.

Comment: There are no smallest or biggest numbers in the open interval $(a,b)$. If you (think you) found $a^1$ to be the smallest, consider that $(a+a^1)/2$ is even smaller, and still within the interval.

Comment: "prove the contradiction".  What contradiction?  You haven't stated any contradiction and nothing you'you've stated implies any contradiction.  Everything you've stayed holds for the rationals as well as the reals, and nothing seems to be stated about uncountability at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually forgot to define what $\ a^1,b^1\,$ are. And it seems I rushed a bit while writing the proof and skipped crucial points. I'll edit the question right away.

Comment: What are the sequences $\omega_i $ supposed to be?  Nested intervals?  Ivm not sure what the argument is supposed to be.  Let (a,b) be (0,3).  Let $a_i= 1-(1/2)^i $ and $b_i = 2+(1/2)^i $ so $a_{\infty}=1;b_{\infty}=2$.  Now what?  What supposedly have have you shown.

Comment: Basically (a_k,b_k) is never empty as (a_k+b_k)/2 is in the interval. As the omegas are *all* the reals some omegas will always occur after a finite number of iterations.  So 1) isn't possible. 2) would imply no omega_k are between a_inf and b_inf which is impossible.  3 is impossible as all a-inf = b-inf =omega-k which would have been accounted for earlier.

Comment: I know between every two real numbers there's infinitely many other real numbers, my point is "can you assume this to prove the uncountability of the real numbers?". Also, it seems there are stil some doubts about the theorem I showed, I took this proof from [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article) this is the second theorem under The proofs section.